# how to write data to text file without sorting

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i want write data from sql table to text file.

```
 Dim Itemlist As New SortedList

sql= select SONO,CustomerName,CustomerCode,ItemCode  from tbl_SalesOrder where SONO =sonumber

  commSQL = New SqlCommand(sql, cnnSQL)
                drSQL = commSQL.ExecuteReader
                While drSQL.Read
                        Dim values(drSQL.FieldCount - 1) As Object
                        Dim fieldCount As Integer = drSQL.GetValues(values)
                        Itemlist.Add(CStr(drSQL(0)) & "_" & CStr(drSQL(3)), values)       

                End While
```

then i am writing this data to text file.

```
sr = New StreamWriter(AppPath & "\Import\SalesOrder.txt")
                For j = 0 To Itemlist.Count - 1

                    Sono = CStr(DirectCast(Itemlist.GetByIndex(j), Object())(0))
                    customername = CStr(DirectCast(Itemlist.GetByIndex(j), Object())(1))
                    customercode = CStr(DirectCast(Itemlist.GetByIndex(j), Object())(2))
                    Sitemcode = CStr(DirectCast(Itemlist.GetByIndex(j), Object())(3))
sql = Trim(Sono) & "|" & Trim(customername) & "|" & Trim(customercode) & "|" & Trim(Sitemcode) 
                    sr.WriteLine(sql)
   Next j
                sr.Close()
                Itemlist.Clear()
                drSQL.Close()
```

but this is writing data to text file in after sorting.my case drsql(3) is the item code,this coming like.'12','25','31','45'.so itemlist sorting this value,and writing to this file.
i dont want to sort like this.i want to write to text file as in the data in table..how i can do that.
any help is very appreciable.

Comment: Um, `ItemList` is a `SortedList`, so why would you be surprised that the data is being sorted?  If you don't want the data sorted then don't put it into a list that sorts it.

Comment: sir i don't want to sort..so how i can re-write the code?

Comment: I know you don't want to sort.  I read you post where it says that you don't want to sort.  That's why I told you to NOT use a list that sorts.  Why would you use a `SortedList` if you don't want the list sorted?  Use something else to store the data.

Comment: this case this is sorting CStr(drSQL(3)) this value..here i can specify which i want to sort?

Comment: Clearly you don't know how a `SortedList` works.  That's not something that we need to teach you.  Go and read about it.  That said, I ask again, why are you using a `SortedList` in the first place if you don't want a list that's sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a `SortedList`, you can use `ArrayList` instead, or more reusable and more beautiful you can use such code:

```
Dim connection = "your connection string"
Dim command = "your command"
Dim table As New System.Data.DataTable
Dim adapter As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(command, connection)
adapter.Fill(table)

Dim builder As New System.Text.StringBuilder
table.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).ToList() _
    .ForEach(Sub(row)
                 builder.AppendLine(String.Join("|", _
                 row.ItemArray.Select(Function(value) String.Format("{0}", value).Trim())))
             End Sub)

System.IO.File.WriteAllText("your file path", builder.ToString())
```

Comment: sir this will write all data to text file

Comment: You are welcome:) feel free to ask any question about the answer:)